# Insert Text in Textfield with a Number as Id (Robotframework)

Tags: swing, robotframework

I'm trying to insert some Text in a Textfield in a swing application via Robotframework. But it doesnt do anything.

The only idea why it does not work is that the id of the text box is a number. For other text fields with string as Id, it went smoothly. Do you have any Idea?

```
*** Variables ***
${stringkurzbesch}  110

Daten des Beschaffungsvorgangs
    [Timeout]  15 seconds
    Select Main Window
    Select Context  Daten des Beschaffungsvorgangs
    Convert To String  ${stringkurzbesch}
    Insert Into Text Field  ${stringkurzbesch}  und hier eine Kurzbeschreibung
```

I only get a Timeout as Result

```
[java] Daten des Beschaffungsvorgangs                    | FAIL |
[java] Test timeout 15 seconds exceeded.
```

Comment: In general If id's are numbers means those are dynamic. Try with other locator to identify element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it does not work *most probably* is that RF tries to operate on the 111. element in the current locating context as [specified here](http://robotframework.org/SwingLibrary/SwingLibrary-1.9.7.html):

> Most
>   of the keywords that operate on a visible component take an argument
>   named identifier, which is used to locate the element. The first
>   matching element is operated on, according to these rules:
>
> - If the identifier is a number, it is used as a **zero-based index for    the particular component type** in the current context. Using
>     indices    is, however, fragile and is strongly discouraged.
> - If the identifier matches to internal name of a component (set using setName method in Java code), that component is chosen.
> - For components that have visible text (e.g. buttons), identifier is also matched against that.
> - Text field keywords also support accessing awt-text fields by prefixing the identifier with awt=

Try `${stringkurzbesch}  "110"` or go for another locating method as described above.